# Detect outdated versions of adobe reader?

Tags: adobe-reader

Due to a bug in 10.1 of Adobe reader our users need to upgrade to 10.1.1 (or downgrade but that is much too convoluted).  Does anybody know of a way to detect if the user has the oldest version of Adobe reader and have them upgrade?

Comment: Detect from where?  A website?  Fat client?  I think you'll have to provide more info for this to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to do this from the web, there is a detection script available from [here](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/AdobeReaderDetect.htm)

The Adobe specific one allows you to determine version number.